# How to access files in recipe-sysroot-native

Tags: cmake, yocto, wayland, yocto-recipe, cmakelists-options

I have an executable in recipe-sysroot-native of my recipe which I intend to use in my CMake for a custom command.
.../xxx-package/git-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/wayland-scanner

What path should I give in my CMake file to access this binary ?

This does not work:

set (WLSCANNER_PATH "/usr/bin/")

error >>

error: '/usr/bin/wayland-scanner', needed by '.../xxx missing and no known rule to make it

Comment: You could try adding something like `EXTRA_OECMAKE:append = " -DWLSCANNER_PATH=${RECIPE_SYSROOT_NATIVE}${bindir}"` to the recipe.

Comment: @skandigraun  Works perfectly. Please post as the answer.